# Error: Maximum function nesting level of '500' reached

Tags: php, symfony

I got this error when I tried to delete cache (**app/console cache:clear**). I increased the level from 100 to 500 but clearly it did not work. Does anyone have an idea what I should do? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable xdebug or change your xdebug.max_nesting_level in php.ini and restart your service.

http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Problem could be caused by a symfony configuration or composer vendor updates. So you need to check your configurations. Some vendor updates could be missed and this could make your script loop.